# Crystal Report vb.net using subreport without relation table

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I use 2 sub reports in my crystal report. Both these reports are not have any link or relation to each other. but have relation with main report with **evidence**.

[image]

my code :

```
    dim mReport As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    dim querymain, query1, query2 As String

    mReport = New CrystalReport1
    querymain = "SELECT * from tblmain where evidence = '" & EvD & "'"
    Call DataSourceConnection_Report() 'my setconnection and setlogon
    mReport.Database.Tables(0).SetDataSource(ExecuteSQLQuery(querymain))

    query1 = "SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE EVIDENCE = '" & EvD & "'"
    mReport.Subreports("sub2").SetDataSource(ExecuteSQLQuery(query1))

    query2 = "SELECT * FROM tbl2 WHERE EVIDENCE = '" & EvD & "'"
    mReport.Subreports("sub3").SetDataSource(ExecuteSQLQuery(query2))
    CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = mReport
```

but it will only show my main report data and leave my sub report empty.

how to fill my sub report ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instantiate your sub-reports like:

```
mReport As New CrystalReport1
querymain = "SELECT * from tblmain where evidence = '" & EvD & "'"
Call DataSourceConnection_Report()
mReport.Database.Tables(0).SetDataSource(ExecuteSQLQuery(querymain))

Dim sub2 As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
sub2 = mReport.OpenSubreport("sub2")
sub2.SetDataSource(ExecuteSQLQuery(query1))

Dim sub3 As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
sub3 = mReport.OpenSubreport("sub3")
sub3.SetDataSource(ExecuteSQLQuery(query2))
```

Comment: my mReport is already CrystalDecision. i declared mReport As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument

Comment: You still need to declare your sub-reports as CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument and open them using your main report. See my updated answer.

Comment: i tried what you sugested to me, but my subreport still empty